# Download file from FTPS to S3

Tags: bash, curl, amazon-s3, matillion

I want to download file from FTPS to s3 using curl command.I tring to solve using bash script.

```
curl ftps://files.are.secure.com/secrets.txt
```

Comment: When `files.are.secure.com` is a server outside aws, you can try to download it first (to an ec2 or local machine) and copy afterwards. Something like `curl ...; aws s3 cp localfile s3_location`. Please show  more details what you tried before we can give a solid answer.

Comment: Are you using Matillion ETL? (I see that as one of the tags.)

Comment: Yes, We have done the task using python.